# Hide examples by color

Tags: javascript, html

**I have this code in cuanto_cuesta.php**

Calcular Precio

Particularidades

Ejemplos

- Problemas de acabados
- Daños estructurales en viviendas unifamiliares
- Carencias en el mantenimiento de edificio de viviendas
- Accidente de un trabajador

**and this one in effects.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ejemplos = $("#Ejemplos");
    var ejemplos_div = $("#ejemplos_div");
    var directory = $(".span_titulo").text();
    var div_loader = $(".loader");
    var partic = $("#particularidades");
    var partic_div = $("#particularidades_div");
    var calcular_precio = $("#calcular_precio");
    var calcular = $("#calc_precio");
    var show = localStorage['show'];

    // ESCONDO LOS DIVS
    partic_div.hide();
    calcular_precio.hide();

    // A SEGUNDA DE LA PROVENIENCIA, MUESTRO EL DIV ELEGIDO
    switch(show){
        case "a_quien_le_interesa":
        //partic_div.show();
                calcular_precio.show();
        calcular.css("color","#D01F3C");
        break;
        case "prueba":
        calcular_precio.show();
        calcular.css("color","#D01F3C");
        break;
        case "cuanto_cuesta":
        calcular_precio.show();
        calcular.css("color","#D01F3C");
        break;
        case "ejemplos":

        ejemplos_div.show();
        ejemplos.css("color","#D01F3C");
        // DESPLIEGA EL CONTENIDO A SEGUNDA DE DONDE HAGAMOS CLICK
        $("#ejemplos_div li").toggle(function(){
            $(this).children(".loader").show(800).fadeIn();
            var height = ejemplos_div.height();
            $(this).children(".mas").attr("src","images/menos.png");
        }, function(){
            $(this).children(".loader").hide(800).fadeOut();
            $(this).children(".mas").fadeOut('slow').attr("src","images/mas.png").fadeIn("fast");
        });
        break;
        case "profesiones":
        calcular_precio.show();
        calcular.css("color","#D01F3C");
        // DESPLIEGA EL CONTENIDO A SEGUNDA DE DONDE HAGAMOS CLICK
        $("#ejemplos_div li").toggle(function(){
            $(this).children(".loader").show(800).fadeIn();
            var height = ejemplos_div.height();
            $(this).children(".mas").attr("src","images/menos.png");
        }, function(){
            $(this).children(".loader").hide(800).fadeOut();
            $(this).children(".mas").fadeOut('slow').attr("src","images/mas.png").fadeIn("fast");
        });
        break;
    }
    div_loader.hide();

    // SHOW/HIDE ESPECIFICIDADES
    $(partic).toggle(function(){
        if(ejemplos_div.is(":visible") == true)
        {
            ejemplos_div.fadeOut("slow").hide();
        }
        if(calcular_precio.is(":visible") == true)
        {
            calcular_precio.fadeOut("slow").hide();
        }
        partic_div.fadeIn("slow").show();
        $(".menu_profesiones a").css("color", "#356AA0");
        partic.css("color","#D01F3C");
        },
        function(){
            partic_div.hide();
    });

    // SHOW/HIDE EJEMPLOS
    $(ejemplos).click(function(){
        if(ejemplos_div.is(":hidden") == true)
        {
            if(partic_div.is(":visible") == true)
            {
                partic_div.fadeOut("slow").hide();
            }
            if(calcular_precio.is(":visible") == true)
            {
                calcular_precio.fadeOut("slow").hide();
            }
            ejemplos_div.show(500);
            $(".menu_profesiones a").css("color", "#356AA0");
            ejemplos.css("color","#D01F3C");
        }
        else{
            ejemplos_div.hide(500);
        }

        // DESPLIEGA EL CONTENIDO A SEGUNDA DE DONDE HAGAMOS CLICK
        $("#ejemplos_div li").toggle(function(){
            $(this).children(".loader").show(800).fadeIn();
            $(this).children(".mas").attr("src","images/menos.png");
        }, function(){
            $(this).children(".loader").hide(800).fadeOut();
            $(this).children(".mas").fadeOut('slow').attr("src","images/mas.png").fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });

    // SHOW/HIDE CALCULO PRECIOS
    $(calcular).click(function(){
        if(calcular_precio.is(":hidden") == true)
        {
            if(ejemplos_div.is(":visible") == true)
            {
                ejemplos_div.fadeOut("slow").hide();
            }
            if(partic_div.is(":visible") == true)
            {
                partic_div.fadeOut("slow").hide();
            }
            calcular_precio.show(500);
            $(".menu_profesiones a").css("color", "#356AA0");
            calcular.css("color","#D01F3C");
        }
        else
        {
            calcular_precio.hide(500);
        }
    });


// Un nuevo SWITCH para comprobar en el caso de que se quiera entrar directamente al apartado EJEMPLOS o CALCULAR PRECIO, sin pasar por PARTICULARIDADES
    switch(red){
        case "ejemplos":
            partic_div.hide();
            calcular_precio.hide();
            ejemplos_div.show();
            ejemplos.css("color","#D01F3C");
            // Despliega el contenido seg�n d�nde se haga click
            $("#ejemplos_div li").toggle(function(){
                $(this).children(".loader").show(800).fadeIn();
                var height = ejemplos_div.height();
                $(this).children(".mas").attr("src","images/menos.png");
            }, function(){
                $(this).children(".loader").hide(800).fadeOut();
                $(this).children(".mas").fadeOut('slow').attr("src","images/mas.png").fadeIn("fast");
            });
        break;

        case "precio":
            partic_div.hide();
            ejemplos_div.hide();
            calcular_precio.show();
            calcular.css("color","#D01F3C");
        break;

        case "particularidades":
            partic_div.show();
            partic.css("color","#D01F3C");
        break;
    }

});
</script>
```

***The problems come when I try to break down examples(ejemplos) cause they open but immediately close..***

Comment: When I load the page without effects.php the Ejemplos load correctly

Comment: http://www.seguroagentesfinancieros.es/index.php?page=Cuanto-Cuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
// SHOW/HIDE EJEMPLOS
    $(ejemplos).click(function(){
        if(ejemplos_div.is(":visible") == true)
        {
            if(partic_div.is(":visible") == true)
            {
                partic_div.fadeOut("slow").hide();
            }
            if(calcular_precio.is(":visible") == true)
            {
                calcular_precio.fadeOut("slow").hide();
            }
            ejemplos_div.show(500);
            $(".menu_profesiones a").css("color", "#356AA0");
            ejemplos.css("color","#D01F3C");
        }
        else{
            ejemplos_div.fadeOut("slow").hide();
// ejemplos_div.hide(500);   -> esto era lo anterior
        }
```

Corrected, for anyone who have a similar problem